# jQuery how to binding event from "selectgroup" plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I can't binding event "onchange"
http://georgepaterson.github.com/jquery-ui/selectgroup/

this plugin hide the selector

```
<select class="select-list">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select-list').selectgroup({
        style: 'popup'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$ is a shortcut for the jQuery keyword so try like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.select-list').selectgroup({
      style: 'popup'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin changes the html structure of the select box into ul so u need to write a function  for the li click like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.ui-selectgroup-list li a').click({
      alert(jQuery(this).html());
    });
});
```

Comment: why you have to add onchange function? may i know the reason

Comment: i have sub selection ex. select country and state or someting...
thanks

Comment: you need to write validation right? for ex if you select country means need to select state

Comment: i mean when select a country (i need bind some event for selection)
then get all state in the country from selected and show state in selection